# Python3 change the text label from another thread tkinter

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

The run method is called in another thread. How can I change the label from the created thread? Well, and back on the filling;) As in the tkinter in the listbox change the element I need *? For example, in Delphi this is done as far as I can remember

```
def run()
i = 0
whileTrue:
    label1["text"] = "test" + str(i)
    i+=1
    time.sleep(1)

p1 = Process(target=run,args=())
p1.start()
```

Thank you for attention

Comment: here's [code example](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/723192/23044) (text in russian)